# Network printing solutions for printers unsupported in a 64bit O/S

Tags: windows, networking, printer, network-shares

We have a small (>10) network of Windows computers, mostly running 32bits XP and one HP LaserJet 2840 printer plugged in (via USB) to one of the XP computers. The computer that has the printer attached shares it and everybody prints to the share.

We're now upgrading some of the computers to windows 7 64bit and have come to realize that even though the printer is connected to a computer that supports it, a driver is still required to print to a share. [The 2840 printer is not supported on W7 64](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Hardware&p=HP%20Color%20LaserJet%202840%20All-in-One%20Printer&v=HP&uid=Q3950AABA&pf=13&pi=5&s=hp5%20laserjet&os=64-bit) so the new computers can't print to it.

My question is whether a solution exists in either software or hardware. I was looking at Google cloud print, but the number of applications that can print to it are very limited atm. Is there something like google cloud print that would create a virtual printer instead of requiring each application to implement a new printing method?

Ideally it'd be a server app installed in the computer where the printer is supported (I'd keep that a 32bit station) and virtual printers that I can install on the other computers.

As far as hardware print servers, do they require drivers as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Microsoft Windows 7 Compatibility lists are more guidelines for your choice of OS/Hardware than strict 'Yes/No' choices. Always check manufacturors websites for that choice. :)

Answer (score 4):

[According to HP the driver is available](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?&objectID=c02536257) in W764bit by using the add printer wizard in Devices and Printers.

So I checked my W7 64bit system and it is there under "HP"

.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that.. I'll have to give that a try. I got my info from here: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Hardware&p=HP%20Color%20LaserJet%202840%20All-in-One%20Printer&v=HP&uid=Q3950AABA&pf=13&pi=5&s=hp5%20laserjet&os=64-bit

Comment: All you can do is try. Hopefully MS is wrong :->